# Set page order when creating OneNote page via Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-onenote

I have a powershell script that's using the Graph API to create a new page in a section of a Note Book. I'd like to be able to either create the new page at the top of the section or arbitrarily set the order of the pages. I can set the Level (indentation) of the page using a PATCH with the body  {"level":"1"} on the page, but it won't allow me to use the same technique to change the page order. I've been digging through docs but can't seem to find anything that exposes page order yet.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct, there are no ways order pages, neither is there any way to order sections or sectiongroups..

One possible way would be to delete the section, and recreate it with the desired order.